# replace a block of lines in file1 with a block of lines in file2

Tags: awk, sed

file1:

```
a xyz 1 2 4  
a xyz 1 2 3  
a abc 3 9 7  
a abc 3 9 2  
a klm 9 3 1  
a klm 9 8 3  
a tlc 3 9 3
```

file2:

```
a xyz 9 2 9  
a xyz 8 9 2   
a abc 3 8 9  
a abc 6 2 7  
a tlk 7 8 9
```

I want to replace the lines that have 'abc' in file1 with the lines that have 'abc' in file2. I'm new to sed, awk, etc. Any help is appreciated.
I tried `cat file1 <(sed '/$r = abc;/d' file2) > newfile` among others but this one simply copies file1 to newfile. I also don't want to generate a new file but only edit file1.
desired output:
(processed) file1:

a xyz 1 2 4
a xyz 1 2 3
a abc 3 8 9
a abc 6 2 7
a klm 9 3 1
a klm 9 8 3
a tlc 3 9 3

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: I edited the question with some more details - does that suffice?

Comment: Can you show (and explain) your expected output given the example files?

Comment: desired output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk, you can use this trick:

```
gawk -v RS='([^\n]* abc [^\n]*\n)+' 'NR == FNR { save = RT; nextfile } FNR == 1 { printf "%s", $0 save; next } { printf "%s", $0 RT }' file2 file1
```

With the record separator `([^\n]* abc [^\n]*\n)+`, this splits the input files into records delimited by blocks of lines with `" abc "` in them. Then,

```
NR == FNR {              # while processing the first given file (file2)
  save = RT              # remember the first record terminator -- the
                         # first block of lines with abc in them
  nextfile               # and go to the next file.
}               
FNR == 1 {                # for the first record in file1
  printf "%s", $0 save   # print it with the saved record terminator
  next                   # from file2, and get the next record
}
{                        # from then on, just echo.
  printf "%s", $0 RT
}
```

Note that this uses several GNU extensions, so it will not work with mawk.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't do any changes to file1 - I ran exact same files in the question

Comment: redirect the output to another file, then move it over file1: `gawk yaddayadda file2 file1 > file1.new && mv file1.new file1`

Comment: still it's the original file1. I tried gawk yaddayadda file2 file1 > file1.new and then checked the difference; diff file1 file1.new and no difference, no change has been made

Comment: Eh, copy/pasto. It's fixed now (`FNR == 1` instead of `NR == 1` for the second block. Silly mistake).